# Taking the input and output of a terminal

Tags: command-line

How can I take the input and the output of a terminal? To be more specific, what I want to do is to take everything that is typed in the terminal, and everything that the "terminal" types (in real time).

Answer (score 2):

`script` should be what you are looking for ([man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/script.1.html)).

Start a logged session with `script /path/to/your/logfile`, every command and its output will be logged into the logfile.

If you need timing info for a realistic replay, use `script -t=/path/to/your/timingfile /path/to/your/logfile`. Afterwards, you can replay the log using `scriptreplay /path/to/your/timingfile /path/to/your/logfile`.

Answer (score 0):

Copy/paste method usually works for simple input/output.

In case you'd like to monitor what's going on within another terminal window try **tmux**.

You may find more [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/tmux.1.html)